# Puppet apache module removes symlink of documentroot

Tags: puppet, apache2, puppet-agent

My documentroot is a symlink. When puppet agent runs, the symlink gets removed. Any ideas?

My code:

```
'qsu.mydomain.de:443':
ssl: true
port: 443
ssl_key:    '/etc/apache2/ssl/qsu.mydomain2.de.key'
ssl_cert:   '/etc/apache2/ssl//qsu.mydomain2.de.crt'
ssl_cipher: 'HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES'
ssl_protocol: 'all -SSLv2 -SSLv3'
priority: '25'
serveradmin: 'support@mydomain2.de'
servername: 'qsu.mydomain.de'
serveraliases:
  - 'mydomain.de'
manage_docroot: false
docroot: '/var/www/mydomain2-web-usr/htdocs'
directoryindex: 'index.html index.htm index.php'
error_log_file:  'qsu.mydomain2.de_ssl_error.log'
access_log_file: 'qsu.mydomain2.de_ssl_access.log'
suexec_user_group: 'mydomain2-web-usr mydomain2-web-usr'
aliases:
  - scriptalias: /cgi-bin/
    path: /var/www/mydomain2-web-usr/cgi-bin/
setenv:
  - 'TYPO3_CONTEXT Production'
directories:
  - path: '/var/www/mydomain2-web-usr/htdocs'
    allow_override: ['all']
    order: 'Allow,Deny'
    options: ['+FollowSymLinks', '-Indexes']
    custom_fragment: |
      <Files ~ (\\.php)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/.conf/fcgid/mydomain2-web-usr/fcgid .php
        Options +ExecCGI
        allow from all
      </Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue when manage_docroots is set to false. It seems like the symlink will always be removed until this bug is fixed. 
There is an open ticket in puppetlabs